# Finding one string inside of another using for loop

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I cannot figure out why my loop is unable to find every occurrence of `myName` in `textToSearch`. It can find only one occurrence if it is near the beginning of `textToSearch`.

```
var textToSearch = "Aaron blue red Aaron green Aaron yellow Aaron";
var myName = "Aaron";
var hits = [];
for(i = 0; i < textToSearch.length; i++){
   if(textToSearch.substring(i, myName.length) === myName){ 
     hits.push(textToSearch.substring(i, myName.length));
   }
}
if(hits.length === 0){
   console.log("Your name wasn't found!");
} else {
   console.log("Your name was found " + hits.length + " times.");
   console.log(hits);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to substring from `i`  to `i + myName.length`.

```js
var textToSearch = "Aaron blue red Aaron green Aaron yellow Aaron";
var myName = "Aaron";
var hits = [];
for(var i = 0; i < textToSearch.length; i++){
   if(textToSearch.substring(i, i + myName.length) === myName){ 
     hits.push(textToSearch.substring(i, i + myName.length));
   }
}
if(hits.length === 0){
   console.log("Your name wasn't found!");
} else {
   console.log("Your name was found " + hits.length + " times.");
   console.log(hits);
}
```

BTW there are better ways to count occurrence

```js
var textToSearch = "Aaron blue red Aaron green Aaron yellow Aaron";

console.log((textToSearch.match(/Aaron/g) || []).length)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use `indexOf`. It takes an offset as a second parameter.

```
var textToSearch = "Aaron blue red Aaron green Aaron yellow Aaron";
var myName = "Aaron";
var hits = 0;
var lastIndex = 0;

while(lastIndex != -1){
   lastIndex = textToSearch.indexOf(myName, lastIndex);
   if (lastIndex != -1) {
     hits++;
     lastIndex++;
   } // Search at the next index
}

if(hits === 0){
   console.log("Your name wasn't found!");
} else {
   console.log("Your name was found " + hits + " times.");
}
```